# Creating a stored procedure and adding date manually to filename

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, concat

I am new to SQL administration and have been tasked with creating some nightly jobs that send an email with certain details contained within a spreadsheet and so far I have the following:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'support',
@recipients = 'test@mail.co.uk',
@subject = 'Post Code Analysis',
@query = N'SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;SET NO COUNT ON;select substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4) as ''Postcode''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 1 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''New Connections''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 2 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Domestic Metered''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 3 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commercial Metered Low''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 4 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commerical Metered High''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 5 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Domestic Keypad''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 6 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Generator''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 7 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commercial Keypad''
from be_crm4_MSCRM.dbo.AccountExtensionBase as a
INNER JOIN be_crm4_MSCRM.dbo.CustomerAddressBase as b ON a.AccountId =     b.ParentId
where New_AccountStage = 7
and AddressTypeCode = 1
and substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2) = ''BT''
group by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4)
order by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4);',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'pca-test.csv',
@query_result_header =0,
@query_result_separator = ' '
```

In the @query_attachment_filename I would like to append the date and have tried using SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] and appending this to the file name as follows:

```
@query_attachment_filename = 'pca-test-' + SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] + '.csv'
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable first - but use format 112 for this. Like this:

```
DECLARE @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(255) = 
    N'pca-test-' + 
    CONVERT(NCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + 
    N'.csv';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'support',
...
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
@query_result_header =0,
@query_result_separator = ' '
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, a stored procedure's argument can be either a string literal or a variable. It certainly cannot be a string expression, like in your attempt. To resolve your issue, you could declare a variable, assign your expression to it and then pass the variable to the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @myfilename nvarchar(255);

SET @myfilename = 'pca-test-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + '.csv';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  …
  @query_attachment_filename = @myfilename,
  …
```

Note also that there are other issues with your method:

1. You do not need to use SELECT with the CONVERT function. You can see above that I simply omitted both the SELECT and the `[DD/MM/YYYY]` column alias. However, if you do use a SELECT in an expression, you need to enclose it in round brackets, like this:

   ```
   … + (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]) + …
   ```

   Aliasing the result of CONVERT is perfectly unnecessary in this case, though – so you can omit the `AS [DD/MM/YYYY]` part.
2. CONVERT with the 103 style will return a string with slashes. However, since you are most likely doing this in Windows, you cannot specify slashes in a file name. You will need to either remove the slashes or replace them with a different delimiter. You can use the REPLACE function in both cases. The following, for instance, replaces the slashes with hyphens:

   ```
   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '-')
   ```

   If you would like to just remove them, use `''` as the third argument.

Comment: As this is 2015, the odds are pretty good that he is dealing with a 2012+ sever, in which case `Format` is a better option than `CONVERT`.

Comment: @jmoreno Do you have any idea how many people are still running 2000, 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2? Also, what makes `FORMAT()` "better"? [It's certainly not performance](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).